# Reading I2C in realtime using SMBus

Tags: linux-device-driver, i2c, smbus

I'm using SMBus (`https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/i2c/dev-interface`) in Linux to retrieve data from i2c device. I'm reading fixed length from specific address on the device, for some reason I'm still able to read the data even after I've disconnected the i2c cable from the computer, This probably means that SMBus is not reading the i2c in realtime and it probably saves data in a cache buffer, Is it true? How can I read i2c data in realtime without cache buffers?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to provide your hardware connection with I2C addresses of the devices connected to a bus. It's quite possible that you are reading some other device's registers.

Comment: I'm opening the i2c device with `/dev/i2c-%d` and reading from address with `ioctl(i2cfile, I2C_SLAVE, address)`